# Get Value of Observable<Record<string, boolean>> using AsyncPipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-observables, async-pipe

I have a service which returns permissions for the logged in user as record. The required observable is defined in my ts file as member variable:

```
permissionsRecord$: Observable<Record<string, boolean>>;
```

When calling the service I pass an array of the authorizations to be checked. In this example I only check for the permission "updateInterval" :

```
constructor() {
    this.permissionsRecord$ = this.japs.userHasPermissionForActions([root.scheduler.order.updateInterval]);
  }
```

The record returned from the service has as key the authorization to be checked. The value obviously can be true or false.
I now want to access the record from my template file like this:

```
<app-scheduler [allowDragAndDrop]="(permissionsRecord$ | async)[root.scheduler.order.updateInterval]">
```

Actually it works fine, but I see an error in the console.

```
SchedulerComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scheduler.order.updateInterval' of null
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SchedulerComponent.html:13)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45258)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44270)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44564)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44277)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44593)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
    at callViewAction (core.js:44636)
```

I am not sure whether my code is correct. How can I access the record "inside" the observable correctly using async from within the template?

Answer (score 0):

If the output is fine, you can try using the safe/elvis operator `?` like so:

```
<app-scheduler [allowDragAndDrop]="(permissionsRecord$ | async).root?.scheduler.order.updateInterval">
```

Comment: I tried `[allowDragAndDrop]="(permissionsRecord$ | async)[root?.scheduler.order.updateInterval]"`. The error persists.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<app-scheduler [allowDragAndDrop]="(permissionsRecord$ | async)?.root.scheduler.order.updateInterval">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the issue persists.